# Twilio API mocking unit testing in Nestjs using Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, twilio, twilio-api

I have this `twilio.service.ts` file. I want to write a unit test in `twilio.service.spec.ts` for two cases in which the verification OTP has been sent successfully or failed with missing parameters.

**twilio.services.ts**:

```
  async startVerification(
   startVerificationDto: StartVerificationDto
   ) {
    try {
      const verificationResponse = await this.twilioClient.verify
        .services("TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE_SID")
        .verifications.create({
          to: `+91${sendVerificationCodeDto.phoneNumber}`,
          channel: "sms",
          locale: "en",
        });
      return verificationResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException("Failed sending OTP");
    }
  }
```

It tried so far:

```
it("Should be able to send verification code on mobile number", async () => {
    const actualRes = await controller.startVerification({
      phoneNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    });

    expect(twilioService.twilioClient.verify.services).toBeCalledWith(
      "TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE_SID"
    );

    expect(actualRes).toEqual({
      sid: "VA_TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE_SID",
    });
  });



  it("Should return error if required parameters are missing", async () => {

    expect(twilioService.twilioClient.verify.services).not.toBeCalledWith(
      "TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE_SID"
    );

    try {
      await controller.startVerification({
        phoneNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      });
    } catch (e) {
      expect(e.message).toBe("Failed sending OTP");
    }
  });
```

My main concern is: how to mock nested functions of Twilio (verify>service>verification>create).
Also, after mocking how do I call or use that in spec.ts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Mocking nested objects and function calls is more annoying than difficult. I think something like this should work for you:

(I'm not sure the relationship between the `controller` and the `twilioService` in your example. I've tried to mock the `twilioClient` on the `twilioService` here, but you may need to adjust that based on how things fit together.)

```js
it("Should be able to send verification code on mobile number", async () => {
  const mockVerificationCreate = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    sid: "VA_TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE_SID"
  })
  const mockVerifyService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    verifications: {
      create: mockVerificationCreate
    }
  })
  twilioService.twilioClient = {
    verify: {
      services: mockVerifyService
    }
  }
 
  const actualRes = await controller.startVerification({
    phoneNumber: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  });

  expect(twilioService.twilioClient.verify.services).toBeHaveBeenCalledWith(
    "TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE_SID"
  );
  expect(mockVerificationCreate).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    to: "+91xxxxxxxxxxx",
    channel: "sms",
    locale: "en",
  });
  expect(actualRes).toEqual({
    sid: "VA_TWILIO_VERIFY_SERVICE_SID",
  });
});
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks, @philnash to response.
here `services` in `twilioService.twilioClient = {
    verify: {
      services: mockVerifyService
    }
  }` is throwing a typescript error stated: 
`Type 'Mock<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'ServiceListInstance': create, each, get, getPage, and 3 more.ts(2740)
Verify.d.ts(25, 12): The expected type comes from property 'services' which is declared here on type 'Verify'
`. How to resolve this?